# How to make one trade in one direction of the trend?

Tags: pine-script, strategy-pattern

I am trying to solve the problem in order to make it perfect in the long, not repeating itself when the target or stop is reached. For example, I open a short trade and I do not want the trade to be opened again when the take profit is reached (since all the conditions for the trade are met), instead, I want the script to wait for the next signal in the opposite direction.

[image]

```PineScript
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © DavydovEV
//@version=5
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)
// Input settings
SLfixed = input.float(0.5, "Stop loss", minval=0.1, maxval=100, step=0.1)
TPfixed = input.float(1, "Take profit", minval=0.1, maxval=100,step=0.1)
// Long/short condition
longCondition = ta.sma(close, 14) > ta.sma(close, 28)
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

shortCondition = ta.sma(close, 14) < ta.sma(close, 28)
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)

longStop = strategy.position_avg_price*(100-SLfixed)/100
longProfit = strategy.position_avg_price*(100+TPfixed)/100
shortStop = strategy.position_avg_price*(100+SLfixed)/100
shortProfit = strategy.position_avg_price*(100-TPfixed)/100

strategy.exit("Exit","My Long Entry Id", stop=longStop, limit=longProfit, when=strategy.position_size>0)
strategy.exit("Exit","My Short Entry Id", stop=shortStop, limit=shortProfit, when=strategy.position_size>0)

// @AndreyD solution
getLastPosSign() =>
    strategy.closedtrades > 0 ? math.sign(strategy.closedtrades.size(strategy.closedtrades-1)) : na

    
plot(ta.sma(close, 14), color=color.green)
plot(ta.sma(close, 28), color=color.red)
plot( getLastPosSign(), style = plot.style_linebr )
```

I already asked this question and @AndreyD suggested the following solution

```PineScript
getLastPosSign() =>
    strategy.closedtrades > 0 ? math.sign(strategy.closedtrades.size(strategy.closedtrades-1)) : na
```

Unfortunately, I didn't manage to attach this function to my script. In this solution, the value changes from -1 to 1 when the direction of the trade changes. In this case, I must write conditions that IF the past value is the same as the current one, then there is no need to open a deal.

I don't really understand if this solution suits me or not, so I could not implement it into my script.

Comment: Can you share the ticker, exchange, tiemframe, date information of the chart in your screenshot?

Comment: BR1! MOEX 5 min Its 3 December, last Friday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use `getLastPosSign()` result with `longCondition` and `shortCondition`:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © DavydovEV
//@version=5
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)
// Input settings
SLfixed = input.float(0.5, "Stop loss", minval=0.1, maxval=100, step=0.1)
TPfixed = input.float(1, "Take profit", minval=0.1, maxval=100,step=0.1)

// @AndreyD solution
getLastPosSign() =>
    strategy.closedtrades > 0 ? math.sign(strategy.closedtrades.size(strategy.closedtrades-1)) : na

lastPos = getLastPosSign()
canEnterLong = nz(lastPos) <= 0
canEnterShort = nz(lastPos) >= 0

// Long/short conditio
longCondition = ta.sma(close, 14) > ta.sma(close, 28)
if (longCondition and canEnterLong)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

shortCondition = ta.sma(close, 14) < ta.sma(close, 28)
if (shortCondition and canEnterShort)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)

longStop = strategy.position_avg_price*(100-SLfixed)/100
longProfit = strategy.position_avg_price*(100+TPfixed)/100
shortStop = strategy.position_avg_price*(100+SLfixed)/100
shortProfit = strategy.position_avg_price*(100-TPfixed)/100

strategy.exit("Exit","My Long Entry Id", stop=longStop, limit=longProfit)
strategy.exit("Exit","My Short Entry Id", stop=shortStop, limit=shortProfit)

plot(ta.sma(close, 14), color=color.green)
plot(ta.sma(close, 28), color=color.red)
plot( lastPos, style = plot.style_linebr )
```